# APE Server: How to configure SSL?

Tags: php, ssl, comet, long-polling, ape

I'm in the middle of trying to implement APE server with SSL, so real-time updates can occur over a secure channel.  Without SSL, this works perfectly.  In order to get SSL working, APE documentation suggests using Stunnel.  The documentation there is a bit unclear to me though.  Some questions:

Has anyone here successfully configured APE with SSL?  Did you use Stunnel?  Do you have a sample stunnel configuration?

What is required to run ape over https/SSL? Wildcard certs? If so, how many certs?  Is there any way to disable this wildcard requirement to reduce cost?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Hello maybe it's late to answer but you can try the following:
in ape.conf you can choose any port I choosed 443 because it was free

```
Server {
        port = 443
        daemon = yes
        ip_listen = 0.0.0.0
        domain = auto
        rlimit_nofile = 10000
        pid_file = /var/run/aped.pid
}
```

in the config.js from the ape demos scripts you can put:

```
APE.Config.baseUrl = 'http://your path to the/APE_JSF/'; //APE JSF 
APE.Config.domain = 'auto'; 
APE.Config.server = 'your_server_where_ape_is_installed:443'; //APE server URL
APE.Config.transport = 2; //! attention not to miss this line (JSONP based communication)
```